# parsing bbl file to an xml file from within pdflatex while typesetting

Tags: natbib, conversion, xml

As editor of a journal I need to translate the bibliography, in a bbl file, into part of an xml file (for potential submission to cross-ref).  It seems best done on the fly by pdfLaTeX so I can also record in the xml the main metadata (authors, title, pages, volume, etc).  Currently I use a scheme for bbl files where the `\bibitem` does not involve brackets, e.g. `\bibitem{Smith99} ...`  The problem is that as soon as the bbl file uses brackets (as in `natbib`) then my scheme fails catastrophically on `\bibitem[blah]{Smith99} ...`  Question: how can I get pdfLaTeX to parse a bbl file, with such `\bibitem[]{}`, into an xml file while pdflatex is typesetting to pdf?

Currently I do the following (hacked from somewhere in latex and executed \AtBeginDocument):

```
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[1]{</unstructured_citation></citation>
    ^^J<citation key="#1"><unstructured_citation>}
...  
\def\j@@Input{%
  \let\jrnltempb\jrnltempa
  \immediate\read\jrnlin to\jrnltempa
  \ifeof\jrnlin
    \immediate\closein\jrnlin
  \else
    \immediate\write\jrnlout{\jrnltempb}
    \expandafter\j@@Input
  \fi}
\typeout{**** Starting to write the bibliography to the xml.}
\newread\jrnlin
\immediate\openin\jrnlin\jobname.bbl\relax
\immediate\write\jrnlout{<citation_list>
    ^^J<citation key="nil"><unstructured_citation>}
\immediate\read\jrnlin to\jrnltempa  
\immediate\read\jrnlin to\jrnltempa
\j@@Input
\immediate\write\jrnlout{</unstructured_citation></citation>
    ^^J</citation_list>}  
\immediate\closein\jrnlin
```

Comment: Try using `xparse`, `\usepackage{xparse}\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\bibitem}{o{}m}{</unstructured_citation></citation>^^J<citation key="#2" opt-arg="#1"><unstructured_citation>}`.

Comment: Does this have to be done with the `.bbl` file? I've seen `.bst` files that deliberately add an XML section to the `.bbl` from BibTeX, which is easier as the data contains no formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing the `.bbl` file is really not the optimal approach here: the file is meant for typesetting and must come from a more structured `.bib` file. A more sensible approach is to modify the `.bst` file used by BibTeX such that it writes XML data to the `.bbl` in form of a 'comment'. The latter can then be easily read back under appropriate conditions. To give more information we'd need a rather more complete example.